# Wishlist Wordpress Plugin issue

Tags: wordpress

I suspected that this had to do with Total Cache when i installed that but it looks like when i  removed that plugin the error remains.  Now I can't register and login.  Any help would be appreciated.

WishList Member Debug. [This is a notification for developers who are working in WordPress debug mode.]
Run-time warning
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Location: /home/collinsit/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wishlist-member/core/PluginMethods.php line number 8719

Comment: foreach ($entry['attributes'] AS $key => $val) {  This is what is on that line

Comment: Look for your wordpress root folder and remove anything related to cache.